# Canonical treatment of tense and modality within formal semantics

Tags: semantics, tense, formal-semantics, modality, montague-grammar

I'm thinking about expressions like "Ronit must have won the game," where we have an intersection of tense and modality.

Conventional wisdom is to use Kratzer's notion of ordering source and graded modality to then formalize the semantics of phrases like above, but there's not much work on the usage of Kratzer's semantics on tensed modal phrases.

I've read through Dowty et al's *Introduction to Montague Semantics,* and within that work, the semantics of tense are formalized almost like modals: We choose a time interval, typically discrete e.g. ${t_1, t_2, t_3}$, and we introduce a variety of operators. Something like the future tense operator $F$, where $[[F(P]]^t_i = 1$ if and only if there exists some $t_j$ such that $t_i < t_j$ and  $[[P]]^t_j = 1$.

However, in a text I read through (that I cannot recall), there's some notion of a formal object called a *history*, which appears to be some kind of acyclic directed graph. The text formalized tense using this object in some way but I can't recall how.

What is the more canonical approach to the formal semantics of tensed expressions? I have not seen many people, if any, use Montague's approach.

Comment: Are the dollar signs for formatting by any chance? If so, what type of formatting are you after?

Comment: @Araucaria-him I’m going for Latex

Comment: Sorry, I meant what effect are you after? (Italics etc)